# How to remove Links from a PDF Document using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, hyperlink, pdfbox

What is the best way to remove links from a PDF using PDFBox. Example: Say I have the following as a page in PDF:

Test [test1](https://stackoverflow.com)

I want that to be converted to

Test test1

removing the link but preserving the text which is test1 in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations)
{
    PDAnnotation annot = annotation;
    if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink)
    {
        PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
        PDAction action = link.getAction();
        if (action instanceof PDActionURI)
        {
            PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
            if ("https://stackoverflow.com".equals(uri.getURI()))
            {
                annotations.remove(link);
                break;
            }                                
        }
    }
}
page.setAnnotations(annotations);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response @tilman. This works for me!

Comment: Glad to hear that, please click on the checkmark icon to make it the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @DushyanthBalasubramanian, I have the same problem but it's not working for me, I am using pdfb0x 2.0.30, please help

Comment: @user3460330 please create a new question, include your code, the PDFBox version and link to the PDF.